# How to use TypeScript infer on a intersection type?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, intersection

I need to turn nested generic types into a array of arrays based on how deeply nested it was.

##### Context

I'm building a query builder for linked data. The dev using this can use regular objects with get/set methods to select data in a graph.

##### Why I currently use intersection

When making a query with `Person.select()` the dev should have access to all the regular get/set methods of the Person class. But *also* some query specific things like `filter()`. This is why I wrapped everything in Query specific objects, which act as a proxy to the original object.

Hence Im converting the type `Shape` to `QueryShape<..> & MappedShape<..>` , where MappedShape takes all the properties of the original shape and converts their type to mapped query objects.

##### The problem

**the infer keyword does not seem to work with intersection.**

When inspecting result and result2, you will see string and string[]. But for result3 and result4 the type is unknown.

I'm open to any other setups.

The example below is a very simplified minimal setup to demonstrate my question.

The expected result of `p.friend.friend` is  `Person[][]`, please ignore that doesn't fully make sense, I avoided a lot of extra complexity with singular/plural. It it helps, think `persons`.

##### Playground setup

See a live example in the TS playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gRQK4QE4gGoEMA2KA8MANAMpxKoDGEAvAHZI44B8UNsUEAHsBHQCYBnKIOCoAlnQDmUAFBQoAfijI0IEmMlT8ZCtVbyoALg7deA4SQAWWSHIXLV6a7YiFS5KhFYAyKAFlbSH4XSHcndRsw4l0vZgMFEzoIADc0AG5ZWVA7QLBg0LcYTh4+IShCjz1vNigAb0MAbQAFKEkoAGsIEDgAM1gAXRN4COw8IpaBqrjMgF9M7PBoeAARLGAsACUIQUZgQlZ2Q1NSixUUZyi3SV60CquYJaIbu9j9eyVYODWNsYJCx6QabvQzDErmcoRDQSaT4F6oCqeEEOL4-LB-NyiGFSYHeUFQZJpVALHLLb7rdG4AgY3GHRHVcFlYRQq5wui3BEAp5tdl3ZpYVB8YBvGqGZQjC6RVwinQPJ40qD8wV0YVI0WJKAYhYAem14n6dDgIjVRCgwCsfCgACskKIoILgBQ6GaLVAUlToKTTRAcIIIKbKHAVZIUGajVIjfwIBBIAiAEZYSgdHku6BgdZWKBB6hQXpwJhwADuEH4UCwAjL-FL5bLqFQWBAYdT9p2ezNS1k3DAcFQwHbdglakKMq5QM1HtNSqFIsOhlH0DMTIJjBwnwxxlRFIx+AVU5VM8aAwWskoOCwgksV3qhlE63ElBEPoglH2xUXZ0qEW2uxwwGYAApjhdcRBBMOpkkLKB-0NKMTAAOTgKMAEphlmIggL9HBn2AAAxOgjH-MAjEHdBt2IGBmCQmhmC-VtfyQww6gUBQgKwvswFqCD7lcf8kMyZioDYqAAEdJUKIwWVcdwKM4iBIMkyBCL41iID7MREwgb823YTDsLw-9RKHK9zy+UYPWkyj+OY3U4AAW3EYBeH4Ex03NLN+ltEsoDAVA4FjYBxB2KApFU4QHXrahqwrfgKWC0LBLgLAo1LBM-VLIMzQizS6OAIDdXNaBE0dXARCvPpmxijYW0dVBklLECoCjXhUHsuqoDjRtVgpLTfyAh0nSgAByQay2ELqNh6-ZaJ-P8rNmWR5pPM8L3ONRtwxQF-Rnep5tPc9mTEzRYW299IUlbcsS0WkmMWvaVoUtx51xegV1YU6DrW8ynpnBoFEDOgsSQF8e0IpA4xwe8swkKRJFwIxCiQ68BN1ShBXWIKsG83yuEbPMER7cQYboXAAHk4ytbCMKQWNeLmwxenEX80H-BmmdQPDFCMcsQER37rO1OyHKcvrVIG80QLp27luEZo0EEDL3u4uw+ZCvtegkMpeKMWXUHl50mP62qCTkxU5aDXioHmhRVYJLBbIgC2DdFo3hvSS2FqyfKrAawsew6QRTVJdyWxmtphEu6RD3a88vIy2QhMFUP2B1vWADpdJff8lLYVg+cN50wFT4n7bmBivZ9v3hBM4smAAQn7aBysTtsGojqRDyj1LY+dTGo3yO5klELzXKsWv49UkO9gAJlqFOg3Tp9M+z6ikeqgbC-VwKBCLu2IFLz3tQKv12rgNz+CNQ0+191AOkD10g-KgrJ9-KAkDoDpDULZ1x77ZvfwAZlnmbOgC8sJLzAIjFeednYF1TpvMo+8E45QACxAN1vPDOwAs4QJzqvfO3k4Ea23vAgQ+9ZBAA)

##### Code

simplified setup in the library:

```
type ToQueryValue<T,Source=null> = T extends string 
  ? QueryString<Source> 
  : T extends Shape 
  ? QueryShape<T,Source> & MappedShape<T,QueryShape<T,Source>> 
  : never;

type MappedShape<T extends Shape,Source> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ToQueryValue<T[P],Source>;
};

type ToDataResult<T> = 
   T extends QueryShape<infer ShapeType,infer Source> 
  ? ToDataValue<ShapeType,Source> 
  : T extends QueryString<infer Source> 
  ? ToDataValue<string,Source>
  : never;

type ToDataValue<Value,Source> = Source extends QueryShape<infer ShapeType, infer ParentSource> 
  ? ToQueryShapeSource<ShapeType,Value, ParentSource> 
  : Value;

//if no source, then just return the value type, else, continue to go deeper back in the path once followed and add an array to the result type
export type ToQueryShapeSource<ShapeType, Value, ParentSource> =
  ShapeType extends null ? Value : ToDataValue<Value, ParentSource>[];


class Shape {
  static select<T extends Shape,QueryResult>(
    this: {new (node: Node): T},
    selectFn:(p:ToQueryValue<T,T>)=>QueryResult)
  {    
    let p = new Shape();
    let queryShape:QueryShape<T,T> = new QueryShape(p);
    let traceResult = selectFn(queryShape as ToQueryValue<T,T>);
    //omitted: path of used properties gets retraced and data gets loaded based on traceResult
    //the actual shape of the data returned is determined by ToDataResult
    return '' as ToDataResult<QueryResult>;
  }
}

class QueryValue<ValueType,Source> {}
class QueryString<Source> extends QueryValue<string,Source>{ }

class QueryShape<ShapeType,Source=null> extends QueryValue<ShapeType,Source>{
  constructor(public original:Shape) {
    //creates a proxy for originalObject
    super();
  }
  filter(filterFn?:any) {
    //omitted
    return this;
  }
}
```

Example use of library:

```
//simplified class
class Person extends Shape {
  get friend():Person { return new Person() }
  get name() { return ''; }
}

//this works, type of result is string[] 
let result = Person.select((p) => {
  return p.name;
})
//this works as well! type of result is string[][] based on a deeper nested path!
let result2 = Person.select((p) => {
  return p.friend.name;
})
//perfect, string[][][] 
let result2b = Person.select((p) => {
  return p.friend.friend.name;
})

//But these both do not work, the type of the result is unknown 
let result3 = Person.select((p) => {
  return p.friend;
})
let result4 = Person.select((p) => {
  return p.friend.friend;
})
```

Comment: agree with jcalz. This looks to me like either a mistake in the example, or perhaps indication that you may want to rethink this approach.

Comment: @jcalz you're totally right, I had over simplified. It's a real but somewhat complex use case for a query builder for graph databases. I have made a new setup, please have a look. thank you!

Comment: @Glitcher I remade the example. Open to other approaches

Comment: Oof, you went from a few lines of code that didn't demonstrate your issue, to a big complicated thing. There isn't anything, like, in between those?  As soon as SO code examples are too long to fit on one screen, I start to question my life choices. I might look at this later after I've had more caffeine, but even so, you'll probably get more engagement if you make a [mre] that is both minimal and reproducible as opposed to just one of them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to echo but yeah this is over the top. I've tried a quick experiment myself and infer seems to work with a union type, but it's possible I've missed something. I think your original post was closer to being a workable question that this one I'm afraid.